# Can we have a Choice-AntiChoice chain?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

Can we have a $\kappa$ sized sequence $\mathcal S$ of transitive domains $\mathcal M_i$ of models of $``\text{ZF + negation of choice}"$, where $\kappa$ is inaccessible, such that for all $i < \kappa$ we have $\mathcal  M_i  \in \mathcal M_{i+1}$ and such that for each $\mathcal M_i$ choice over$\mathcal M_i$ applies in $\mathcal M_{i+1}$ , i.e., for each element $s$ of $\mathcal M_i$ there exists a set $c \in \mathcal M_{i+1}$ such that $c$ has exactly one element from each element of $s$ among its elements.

Comment: Doesn't the naive approach work? Take $\kappa$ of sufficient cardinal strength (e.g. $\kappa$ Mahlo) and recursively build your sequence: At stage $i+1$, first collapse $\mathcal{M_i}$ to be countable (which immediately gives that choice holds) and then extend it one step further to violate choice. Wrap all of this into a sufficiently large collapse of $V$ and you're done.

Comment: can you present that with some detail as an answer?

Comment: Do you care about $\kappa$'s cardinality or only its order-type? Because in the construction I've outlined above, $\kappa$ will become countable and the question seems to become quite a bit harder if you want to preserve that $\kappa$ is inaccessible. (The existence of suitable generic filters, in $V$, becomes problematic.)

Comment: well the idea is that $\kappa$ is inaccessible.

Comment: Okay, so this won't work (at least not without modification). I've translated your question in my head to 'can we have arbitrarily long choice/anti-choice sequences?' and only when typing the answer did I realize that you may have had something different in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following works (and it's not even an iterated forcing argument):

Fix $\kappa$ inaccessible . For a [worldly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldly_cardinal) cardinal $\mu<\kappa$, let $\mathbb{P}_\mu$ be the forcing consisting of maps from $\mu$ to $2$ with domain of cardinality $<\mu$. Let $(\mu_\eta)_{\eta<\kappa}$ enumerate the worldly cardinals $<\kappa$ in increasing order *(recalling that every inaccessible cardinal is a limit of worldly cardinals)*, and consider the forcing notion $$\mathbb{P}=\{P\in\prod_{\eta<\kappa}\mathbb{P}_{\mu_\eta}: \vert\{\alpha<\kappa: P(\alpha)\not=\emptyset\}\vert<\kappa\}$$ be the $<\kappa$-support product of the $\mathbb{P}_\mu$s. Note that forcing with $\mathbb{P}$ preserves the inaccessibility of $\kappa$ (think about how $\mathbb{P}$ "splits" into a $\mu$-c.c. and a $\mu$-closed piece, for every $\mu<\kappa$, and count the nice names ...).

Let $G$ be $\mathbb{P}$-generic. For $\eta<\kappa$, let $G_\eta=G\upharpoonright \mu_\eta$, and note that $G_\eta$ is set-generic over the ZFC-model $L_{\mu_{\eta+1}}$. Now by a standard symmetric submodel argument we can whip up for each $\eta$ a $W_\eta$ such that:

- $L_{\mu_{\eta+2}}\subset W_\eta\subset L_{\mu_{\eta+2}}[G_{\eta+1}],$
- $W_\eta\models$ ZF+$\neg$AC, and
- $G_\eta\in W_\eta$.

The $W_\eta$s satisfy the desired properties (the third condition is what ensures that each one contains a well-ordering of the earlier ones).

---

EDIT: Deleted a broken idea.

Comment: The second part is false. If $\eta=\beth_\delta+1$ where $\delta$ has uncountable cofinality, then $V_\eta\cong\mathcal P(\omega_\delta)$ and by a theorem of Shelah, $L(\mathcal P(\kappa))$ satisfies choice when $\kappa$ is singular of uncountable cofinality.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh that's *fascinating*! I'd never seen that before. Clearly my memory is off - do you know if it holds for successor-of-successor $\eta$s? (And do you have a citation for Shelah's result?)

Comment: Not off hand, I'll try to find one tomorrow or so. I think it's in the choiceless PCF papers, maybe Shelah 835.